# jQuery - .hover .fadeIn/Out - not fully fading in?

Tags: jquery

If you take a look at: http://sweetnation.co.uk/store/index.php?route=product/category&path=60

and hover over the categories section of the menu, the categories fade in, but sometimes they fade in half way and you cant see them. I have no idea what's causing it.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".hover_bitch, #menu").hover(function(){
        $("#menu").stop().fadeIn("fast");
    },function(){
        $("#menu").stop().fadeOut("fast");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `.stop(true, true)`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".hover_bitch, #menu").hover(function(){
        $("#menu").stop(true, true).fadeIn("fast");
    },function(){
        $("#menu").stop(true, true).fadeOut("fast");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

problem with your `.stop()`

Try to use [**jQuery HoverIntent**](http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html) and remove your `.stop()`